# A question on how to edit the following button's height and width

Tags: html, css, web

I have these lines of code on separate sheets and there isn't any referencing error but when I .change height and width values nothing changes it just displays the button depending on size of text
`

Menu

```
<style>
.button{
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: 'Noto Sans';
  background-color: #8361ff;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</html`
```

..expecting the button's width and height to change

Comment: Can you edit this and show the html?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you're trying to select a class but you don't have that class in your HTML. When you want to select a type of element (like a button), you would refer to it in CSS like this:

```
button {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

The HTML would not have to have anything special added to it.

Now let's take a look at what happens when you're using a class instead of an element selector (which is what your code is doing right now). The CSS should look like this. Note the dot in front of *button*:

```
.my-button-class {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

Now that your CSS is referring to a **class**, your HTML **must also have that class**. Here's how you would do that:

```
<button type="submit" class="my-button-class">My Button</button>
```